# Black background with light color gradient on top of it in semi-circle shape

Tags: java, android, user-interface, shapes

[Gradient should be very light on black background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGtTm.png) 
I am trying to get a semi-circle with black background and light blue gradient on top of it (which is visible like a glow or shadow). I have tried many ways using  tags in Android but not able to get exactly what i need. Can someone please help in achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a circular gradient using `android:type="radial"`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="250"
        android:startColor="your start color" android:endColor="your end color" />
</shape>
```

**for semi circle you can use this code**

```
public class SemiCircleDrawable extends Drawable {

    private Paint paint;
    private RectF rectF;
    private int color;
    private Direction angle;

    public enum Direction
    {
        LEFT,
        RIGHT,
        TOP,
        BOTTOM
    }

    public SemiCircleDrawable() {
        this(Color.BLUE, Direction.LEFT);
    }

    public SemiCircleDrawable(int color, Direction angle) {
        this.color = color;
        this.angle = angle;
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color);
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        rectF = new RectF();
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    /**
     * A 32bit color not a color resources.
     * @param color
     */
    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        paint.setColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();

        Rect bounds = getBounds();

        if(angle == Direction.LEFT || angle == Direction.RIGHT)
        {
            canvas.scale(2, 1);
            if(angle == Direction.RIGHT)
            {
                canvas.translate(-(bounds.right / 2), 0);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            canvas.scale(1, 2);
            if(angle == Direction.BOTTOM)
            {
                canvas.translate(0, -(bounds.bottom / 2));
            }
        }


        rectF.set(bounds);

        if(angle == Direction.LEFT)
            canvas.drawArc(rectF, 90, 180, true, paint);
        else if(angle == Direction.TOP)
            canvas.drawArc(rectF, -180, 180, true, paint);
        else if(angle == Direction.RIGHT)
            canvas.drawArc(rectF, 270, 180, true, paint);
        else if(angle == Direction.BOTTOM)
            canvas.drawArc(rectF, 0, 180, true, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        // Has no effect
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        // Has no effect
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        // Not Implemented
        return 0;
    }

}
```